# JEST Test.DataReducer is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

While testing the React Native project, I got an error related to redux. How can I fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - export default (state=....)=>{
or 
 - const DataReduser = (state.....
       export default DataReduser
```